# Windows 7: Map to 4 shares on same SMB host?

Tags: windows-7, linux, network-shares, samba, hosts

I have a Lubuntu 16.10 host file server with 4 Samba shares, each relating to a different physical disk. I want to map to each of these 4 shares simultaneously from Windows 7 (as I want to run scheduled backups to them every night), but have hit the "multiple connections to a server or shared resource" restriction in Windows.

I have managed to connect to 3 of the shares by specifying the host name for the first connection, the IP address for the 2nd, and a dummy DNS name in my hosts file for the third ("net use t: \dummyhostname\sharename"). If I try to use another dummy DNS name in the hosts file for the 4th share ("net use u: \dummyhostname2\sharename2") I can access it, but for some reason can't write to it.
The 4th share is defined in exactly the same way as the others in smb.conf:

```
[Samsung2Tb1]
comment = Samsung 2Tb1
path = /media/myuser/Samsung2Tb1
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
force user = myuser
```

Any idea why I don't have write access to this, and how I can get it?

This is the error message I get:

[image]

Comment: There is no restriction unless you want to connect using different credentials. Is that really what you’re doing?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow what you mean. I want to connect using the same credentials for all 4 shares. I can write to the first 3, but not the 4th ???

Comment: I can map as many drives as I want. // Please provide a screenshot of what happens. Also, what do you mean by “write to”? I thought you couldn’t map the fourth?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3r5dupb6mef8lbv/copyerror.jpg?dl=0

Comment: The above is a screenshot of the error. I tried to copy the "GN 2013c.pdf" file from the left window to the V: drive in the right window. The V: drive was mapped as follows: "net use v: \\microserver1\samsung2tb1", where "microserver1" is mapped to 192.168.1.251 in my hosts file. The T: and U: drives in the right window are mapped to identically-configured shares on the same host (192.168.1.251), and I can copy files to both of them without any problem.

Comment: ...and the Y: drive is also mapped to a share on the same host (192.168.1.251). I can copy files to that without any problems.

Comment: So, yeah, that's totally not the error you mentioned in your question. Please update your question, I'll inline the image later. // Did you check the filesystem permissions on your NAS/whatever?

Comment: I think I said "I can access it, but for some reason can't write to it" - which is what the screenshot shows? So it was indeed a file permissions issue on the host. I thought I'd created them all identically (I used the same script), but for some reason the drive in question had RW permissions for the root account account only. Have now corrected it and can write from the WIndows box. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

First, about the error you're *not* getting:

> Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

It only appears when you try to use different accounts to connect to the same server. Apparently, you're not doing that, so the entire stunt with DNS aliases and whatnot is unnecessary.

Now, the error you *are* getting indicates a permission error. It can occur on multiple levels:

- Samba share permissions
- Server-side file system permissions
- Read-only mounts/special file systems

In your case, we can rule out Samba problems because you copied the share definition.